# Lognormal RVs: How much probable it is finding values near the mode than near the average?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, error-function

**Log-Normal RVs: How much probable it is finding values near the mode than near the average?**

*Intro_______________*

I was trying to got an insight into this question, and I think in the following: since it is not possible to speak about the probability of a simple point in a continuous probability distribution, because the CDF will integrate with the same number on both of its limits of integration, which equals zero, then maybe it is possible to compare both probabilities on a infinitesimal interval if the length is the same for both scenarios,
$$\text{ratio} = \lim\limits_{q \to 0^+} \dfrac{P(\nu-q<X<\nu+q)}{P(\bar{x}-q<X<\bar{x}+q)}$$

where $\nu = e^{\mu-\sigma^2}$ is the **mode** and $\bar{x} = e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$ is the **average** of the [Log-Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution): I am using the same description than Wikipedia in order to reduce explanations, and I am avoiding the use of *expected value* term in purpose, since for a [skewed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) the "average" don't coincide with the value you *expect to see more frequently* which is given by the "mode".

Now, for the [Log-Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) I will have that:
$$P(X<x) = \Phi\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\frac12\left[1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$
and since $P(a<X<b) = P(X<b)-P(X<a)$, after some simplifications I will have that the ratio I am looking for will look like:
$$\text{ratio} = \lim\limits_{q \to 0^+} \dfrac{\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{\ln\left(e^{\mu-\sigma^2}+q\right)-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{\ln\left(e^{\mu-\sigma^2}-q\right)-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{\ln\left(e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}+q\right)-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{\ln\left(e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}-q\right)-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$

Unfortunately it is way more complicated than what I can unravel by myself, and neither [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%5B%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m-a%5E2%29%2Bq%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m-a%5E2%29-q%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5D%2F%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m%2Ba%5E2%2F2%29%2Bq%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m%2Ba%5E2%2F2%29-q%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5D%2Cq-%3E0%5E%2B%5D&lang=es) could got a solution, but I started to place numbers where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are and I found some interesting results:

1. If I chose $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 1$, instead of having an undefined ratio or a zero value (as I were afraid due what I mentioned at the beginning), the formula do find a finite limit value in [wolfram-alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%5B%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%281-1%5E2%29%2Bq%29-1%29%2F1%2Fsqrt%282%29%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%281-1%5E2%29-q%29-1%29%2F1%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5D%2F%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%281%2B1%5E2%2F2%29%2Bq%29-1%29%2F1%2Fsqrt%282%29%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%281%2B1%5E2%2F2%29-q%29-1%29%2F1%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5D%2C+q-%3E0%5E%2B%5D&lang=es) showing $\text{ratio} = e^{9/8}$
2. So I started to change values to see what happens: I notice that if I change $\sigma$ the ratio change values, but when I change $\mu$ for a fixed $\sigma$ the ratio doesn't change at all.
3. If the variable $\mu$ show to be a dummy, then I think why not just making it zero, and with this [wolfram-alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%5B%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28-a%5E2%29%2Bq%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Fa%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28-a%5E2%29-q%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Fa%29%5D%2F%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28a%5E2%2F2%29%2Bq%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Fa%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28a%5E2%2F2%29-q%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Fa%29%5D%2Cq-%3E0%5E%2B%5D&lang=es) shows an interesting result: it cannot solve the ratio but it gives a series expansion: $$\text{ratio}\approx \exp\left(\frac{3\sigma^4-\ln\left(e^{-\sigma^2}\right)^2+\ln\left(e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) + O(q^2)$$ which [can be reduced](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28%283x%5E4-ln%28e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%29%5E2%2Bln%28e%5E%28x%5E2%2F2%29%29%5E2%29%2F%282x%5E2%29%29&lang=es) to $$\text{ratio}\approx e^{\frac{9\sigma^2}{8}} + O(q^2)$$ Here I also noticed that for different values of $\sigma$ the limits found by Wolfram-Alpha actually matches perfectly the values of the approximation, so I am believing that Wolfram-Alpha indeed solved the ratio formula when it did the series expansion.
4. Following this intuition, I tried to expand the first ratio in its series expansion and [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+%28%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m-a%5E2%29%2Bq%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m-a%5E2%29-q%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5D%2F%5Berf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m%2Ba%5E2%2F2%29%2Bq%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29-erf%28%28ln%28e%5E%28m%2Ba%5E2%2F2%29-q%29-m%29%2Fa%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5D%29%2C++near+q%3D0) found the following: $$\text{ratio}\approx \exp\left(\frac{3\sigma^4-\left(\mu-\ln\left(e^{\mu-\sigma^2}\right)\right)^2 +\left(\mu- \ln\left(e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\right)\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) + O(q^2)$$ which [can be reduced](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28%283a%5E4-%28m-ln%28e%5E%28m-a%5E2%29%29%29%5E2%2B%28m-ln%28e%5E%28m%2Ba%5E2%2F2%29%29%29%5E2%29%2F%282a%5E2%29%29) **again** to $$\text{ratio}\approx \exp\left(\dfrac{9\sigma^2}{8}\right) + O(q^2)$$ explaining why the variable $\mu$ was behaving as a dummy variable.

*Main question________________*

Given the results I found, I want to ask the following:

- **It is possible to prove that for a Log-Normal distribution the ratio $$\text{ratio} = \lim\limits_{q \to 0^+} \dfrac{P(\nu-q<X<\nu+q)}{P(\bar{x}-q<X<\bar{x}+q)} \equiv \exp\left(\dfrac{9\sigma^2}{8}\right)$$ happen to be true?**
- **Is it correct to say that for a Log-Normal distributed random variable, the probability of finding a value near the "Mode" is $\exp\left(\dfrac{9\sigma^2}{8}\right)$ times higher than the probability of finding a value near their "Average"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ratio is simply the ratio of probability densities, because for a continuous random variable $X$,
$$f_X(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+} \frac{\Pr[x < X \le x + \Delta x]}{\Delta x}.$$  That your limit uses the variant $\Pr[x-q < X < x+q]$ is immaterial.*

As such, your ratio has the value
$$R = \frac{f_X(e^{\mu - \sigma^2})}{f_X(e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2})} = \frac{e^{-\mu + \sigma^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}{e^{-\mu - 5\sigma^2/8}} = e^{9\sigma^2/8}.$$

---

*The reason is because where the derivative is defined,
$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}.$$

As for the meaning of this ratio, it is a **likelihood ratio**.  Specifically, it is the likelihood ratio of observing the mode versus the mean.  It does not represent the idea that the probability of observing (approximately) the mode is $e^{9\sigma^2/8}$ more than the mean, because the density is not a probability.  For instance, if I said event $A$ had a probability of $\Pr[A] = 0.01$, and event $B$ is $e^{9\sigma^2/8}$ times more likely than $A$, that is, $\Pr[B] = e^{9\sigma^2/8}\Pr[A]$, then that would seem to suggest that for sufficiently large $\sigma$, $\Pr[B] > 1$, which is absurd.

To illustrate the issues arising from confusing a likelihood for a probability, consider the following example. Suppose $\mu = -1$ and $\sigma = 1$.  Then it is not difficult to see that the lognormal mode is $\nu = e^{-2}$ and the lognormal mean is $\bar x = e^{-1/2}$. The values of the density at these points are
$$f_X(\nu) = \frac{e^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \approx 1.78794, \\
f_X(\bar x) = \frac{e^{3/8}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \approx 0.580458.
$$
And while it is true that their ratio is exactly $e^{9/8}$, the values of these densities are not probabilities.  To rectify this, we might be inspired to let
$$p(x,\delta) = \Pr[|X - x| \le \delta],$$ for some suitably small $\delta > 0$, and consider the ratio $p(\nu, \delta)/p(\bar x, \delta)$.  Let's try this for $\delta = 0.01$:

$$\frac{p(e^{-2}, 0.01)}{p(e^{-1/2}, 0.01)} \approx \frac{0.0357261}{0.0116106} = 3.07702.$$
This is pretty close, but not exactly equal to $e^{9/8}$.  But what if we had chosen $\mu = -1$, $\sigma = 2$?  Then
$$\nu = e^{-5}, \quad \bar x = e$$ and for the same $\delta$, we get
$$\frac{p(e^{-5}, 0.01)}{p(e, 0.01)} \approx \frac{0.0611685}{0.000890168} = 68.7157$$
and this is not at all close to the theoretical result of $e^{36/8} = 90.0171$.  What happened?  The problem here is that the range of $\delta$ for which this ratio becomes "good" is dependent on $\mu$ and $\sigma$.  Yes, if it's "small enough," then it must work.  But as we make $\delta$ smaller, the probabilities of being "close to" $\nu$ or $\bar x$ also get vanishingly small.  This is what you were doing when you wrote $O(q^2)$ in your work.  You were trying to quantify the magnitude of error in your approximation of the likelihood ratio as a function of the half-width of the interval.

So it's not as if the ratio doesn't have some kind of interpretation in terms of relative probabilities, but care must be taken when we talk about such ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Does this mean is not possible to measure how much probable is to find values near the Mode than it is near the Average? (since the series expansion near $q=0$, for small $q>0$ it is still independent of the variable $q$). 
 Also in the same line, Could you elaborate on the intuition of the meaning of the Likelihood ratio in this context?

Comment: @Joako: Your question about "near the mode" is not well posed because "near" has no precise mathematical meaning.  But a reasonable way to interpret it as a mathematical question is exactly what you did in the first bullet, by dividing the probabilities and taking the limit.  So in that sense it *is* possible. And this answer proves that the result is exactly what you conjectured it is.

Comment: @NateEldredge But how could be possible to be right and at the same time mistaken?, I think the answer show that my second bullet would lead to probabilities higher than $1$ which make no sense, even worst, the formula will lead to the same conclusion even if the interval is not infinitesimal (as example, $q=0.1$), so now I am confused.. it should be wrong quantitatively speaking.

Comment: @NateEldredge playing with numerical values I think the equality of the first bullet is false, it is just a first order approximation near $q=0$.... but I still don't know if taking limits different from zero, let say $q\to 0.1$, will still lead to probabilities higher than $1$.

Comment: From the Wiki page for [Log-Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) is stated that $\mu$ must be positive: Does this change your analysis?

Comment: @Joako The Wikipedia article is clearly incorrect.  If you look at the table in the article, it has the correct range for $\mu$.  This is because $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance parameters for the normal distribution, $X = \mu + \sigma Z$, where $Z$ is standard normal, and $e^X$ is lognormal.  It doesn't matter if $\mu$ is negative; the transformed variable still exists.

Comment: @Joako Someone, on 26 November 2023 (today), revised the Wikipedia article and introduced this error, which was not present in the previous version dated 22 November 2023.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Log-normal_distribution&diff=1186903036&oldid=1186367294

Comment: wow.. this is weird, I saw it also the last time. Maybe there is a fight among reviewers. Thanks again for your dedication to my question, but it make sense also for me that the location value could be negative also, but after seen it in Wikipedia I start to have doubts about it (in math stuff it is quite accurate in my experience).